# Webpack silently not building nested scss

Tags: typescript, webpack, sass

I have a fairly simple webpack file which takes some typescript + scss and processes it. 
I noticed that when I have nested scss, webpack will not transpile it into css at all. I have no data of it in the transpiled file. But when I have un-nested scss, everything works as expected.

As an example, this is the scss I have that does not build with my webpack config.

```
.my-gallery {
  border: 2px solid red;
  &-img {
    border: 2px solid blue;
  }
}
```

However, when I have my scss like this, everything works as expected.

```
    .my-gallery {
      border: 2px solid blue;
    }

    .my-gallery-img {
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
```

What could I be doing wrong in my webpack config? Below I have attached my current configuration and my dev dependencies.

```js
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: ["./app/main.ts"],
  watch: true,
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "static")
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // Transform es6+ js & ts into es5 js.
        test: [/.js$|.ts$/],
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/typescript"]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        // Transform scss to css, minify it, apply autoprefixer via postcss
        test: [/.css$|.scss$/],
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader",
          "postcss-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts"]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      //Writes all styles to a single style.css file.

      filename: "css/[name].css"
    })
  ]
};
```

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.3.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.1",
    "webpack": "^4.36.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to give an update. I discovered that I fat fingered something thing in my template. There was nothing wrong with my webpack config.

In my template, I accidentally put a `"` in a class name.

```
<div class="my-gallery">
  {{ range $i, $imgsrc :=  $.Page.Params.Images }}
  <div class="my-gallery-img""> <!-- right here --> 
    <img 
      class="lazy"
      src="/img/placeholder.png"
      data-src="{{$imgsrc}}" alt="">
  </div>
  {{ end }}
</div>
```

Cheers